# ¿Por qué el css no me agrega los estilos a mi página en HTML?

Tags: css, html5, vscode

Estoy haciendo mi página en vscode y al momento de empezar a agregar los estilos en el css, no me los carga.
Estoy utilizando fontawesome y bootstrap

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Estoy creando un login con html5 y css, mi problema es que css no realiza ningun cambio en el dise;o y no sé por qué.

Comment: Puedes consultar este sitio para tener una mejor idea: [ask]

Comment: probablemente sea el nombre de los campos a los que querias cambiarle los estilos o pueden ser tambien que cambies el '#' por un '.' a la hora de llamar los campos
tuve ese mismo problema y solo asi lo pude solucionar

Comment: Tienes que lindera el src de css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

primero que todo revisa los comentarios de la comunida que te aportan en esta pregunta.

para responder tu pregunta hay varias formas de agregar `css` a un archivo `html`, si es externo como es este caso agregas la siguiente linea de codigo dentro de las **etiquetas** `head`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="aqui das la ruta del archivo css">
```